# JPA Hibernate : A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using two address for a person i.e. present and permanent address.
Each address has an District.
I am showing a district list in a dropdown at the frontend so that user can select a district among them.
So this case must be occur that one has present and permanent address same. So one can select two same district for both address.

Now come to the point. If one set same district for both address, JPA Hibernate show an error following as at the same time two same district are being updated.

```
nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

Person.java

```
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "permanent_adrs_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address permanentAddress;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "present_adrs_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address presentAddress;
}
```

Address.java

```
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String village;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "district_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private District district;
}
```

District.java

```
@Table(name = "district")
public class District implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that is throwing the exception in your question?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, you have two `District` or `Address` objects that have the same value for `id`, but are different objects i.e. `obj1 != obj2`.

This is illegal in JPA. The usual solution to this is, to load objects which you refer to from other objects.

For example, do something like this:

```java
Person p = ...
p.getPermanentAddress().setDistrict(
  entityManager.find(District.class, p.getPermanentAddress().getDistrict().getId())
);

p.getPresentAddress().setDistrict(
  entityManager.find(District.class, p.getPresentAddress().getDistrict().getId())
);

repository.save(p);
```